# Web audio API: how to silence all oscillators and pause melody

Tags: javascript, web, audio, web-audio-api

I make a new oscillator for each note I play.

```
function playSound(freq, duration) { 
    var attack = 5,
        decay = duration,
        gain = context.createGain(), 
        osc = context.createOscillator(); 

    gain.connect(context.destination); 
    gain.gain.setValueAtTime(0, context.currentTime);
    gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0.1, context.currentTime + attack / 1000);
    gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, context.currentTime + decay / 1000);

    osc.frequency.value = freq;
    osc.type = "sine";
    osc.connect(gain); 
    osc.start(0);

    setTimeout(function() { 
        osc.stop(0);
        osc.disconnect(gain);
        gain.disconnect(context.destination);
    }, decay)
}
```

The melody is played in a for loop, where playSound is called. When I click the pause button, I want to silence the melody and pause the for loop so that if I click the play button again, the melody resumes. How do I access all the current oscillators to disconnect them?

Comment: It's worth noting that in web audio you cannot pause an audio node, but must stop it and when resuming must recreate the node.  You might already know this.  @cwilso answer below is correct, you need to store off a reference to any nodes you want to interact with at a later time.

Answer (score 6):

You can't, in this code.

1) There is, by design, no introspection of the node graph in the Web Audio API - it enables optimizing garbage collection, and optimizes for large numbers of nodes. Two potential solutions - either maintain a list of playing oscillators, or connect them all to a single gain node (that is, connect their envelope gain node to a "mixer" gain node), and then disconnect (and release references to) that gain node.

2) Not sure what you mean by "pause the for loop" - I presume you have a for loop wrapped around the play note method?

Answer (score 0):

You can [suspend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/suspend) the audio context.

```js
const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
audioCtx.suspend();
audioCtx.resume();
```